# How can I delete dataGridView row on keyboard delete key press ? c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How can I delete a selected row on keyboard delete key press ( remove from dataGridView and delete from the database ) ?

here how I populate the dataGridView :

```
 private void GetDate()
        {

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id as [ID],description as [Description],unit as [Unit], qty as [Quantity],unitRate as [Unit Rate], amount as [Amount], _datetime as [Date] FROM tbl_BOQ WHERE projectId = "+id, conn);
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Clear();

            adapter.Fill(table);


            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;


        }
```

Comment: Hi, show some code, how is your grid getting populated? how is your page/form looking like? ASP.NET or Windows Forms?

Comment: it is windows form application not ASP.NET

Comment: hei ..how u did this one..plz help me

Answer (score 8):

I use the DataGridView's KeyDown event, and in the handler determine if it was the Delete key that was pressed:

`if e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete...`

Then find which item/row to delete by getting the SelectedRows property if your DataGridView is on  FullRowSelect or RowHeaderSelect mode, else you can determine the row with something like this:

`i = SelectedCells[0].RowIndex`

then:

`DataGridView.Rows[i].DataBoundItem`

You would then simply need to delete the corresponding record from the database, and possibly refresh the DataGridView depening on how its tied in...

Comment: keydown event is not firing for me

Comment: I used KeyUp because KeyDown is not firing.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event of the [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events.aspx)?

Then you could use the [SelectedRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx) property of your DataGridView.

Comment: I think `CurrentRow` would be appropriate

Comment: That would depend upon your setting for MultiSelect. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.multiselect.aspx

Comment: Its a different collection all together

Comment: Well, the question is how to delete the SELECTED row. If it is multiselect sooner or later, iterating over the SelectedRows rows would be the right decision, I think.